# Remove 10-base x tick labels from matlab2tikz plot

Tags: pgfplots, matlab, matlab2tikz

I am trying to extract some plots from Matlab for XeLaTex using Matlab2Tikz. All goes well, except the plot with the loglog scale (I included a figure, see below). The left bottom plot shows a loglog scale with 10-base tick labels on the y-axis and a logarithmic scale on the x-axis but without 10-base. When performing the matlab2tikz command, I get 10-base x tick labels which I clearly don't need. Instead, I would like to have it the way Matlab plots it.

I haven't found a similar problem here on stackexchange so I thought I'd ask it myself.

Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT: Here is the code:

```
\begin{axis}[%
width=\fwidth,
height=\fheight,
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={white!15!black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xmode=log,
xmin=1,
xmax=8,
xminorticks=true,
every outer y axis line/.append style={white!15!black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ymode=log,
ymin=0.0001,
ymax=1,
yminorticks=true,
ylabel={E(K)},
at=(plot3.below south west),
anchor=above north west
]
\addplot [color=red,solid,mark=o,mark options={solid},forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{1 0.0711717716815872\\
2   0.0115273918542792\\
3   0.00554837295582636\\
4   0.00390493819982627\\
5   0.00257462558614867\\
6   0.000676170571559625\\
7   0.000211268404410399\\
8   0.000179355383693616\\
};
\end{axis}
```

[image: Bottom plot left is how i Like it to be, bottom plot right is how i get it in LaTeX]

Comment: Please provide the code.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to this. I have edited it :-)!

Comment: No problem. However, is that the resulting LaTeX code?

Comment: See the answer provided. The same option applies in your concrete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the y-axis, you can use `ytickend` to provide a list of the desired tick locations (it admits the `...` shortcut). In your case, you can use

```
ytickten={-4,-2,0}
```

For the x-axis, you need to change the tick representation using

```
  xtick=data,
  xticklabel=\pgfmathparse{e^\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[%
  scale only axis,
  separate axis lines,
  every outer x axis line/.append style={white!15!black},
  xmode=log,
  xmin=1,
  xmax=8,
  every outer y axis line/.append style={white!15!black},
  every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  ymode=log,
  ymin=0.0001,
  ymax=1,
  ylabel={E(K)},
  anchor=above north west,
  ytickten={-4,-2,0},
  xtick=data,
  xticklabel=\pgfmathparse{e^\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
]
\addplot [color=red,solid,mark=o,mark options={solid},forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{
1 0.0711717716815872\\
2   0.0115273918542792\\
3   0.00554837295582636\\
4   0.00390493819982627\\
5   0.00257462558614867\\
6   0.000676170571559625\\
7   0.000211268404410399\\
8   0.000179355383693616\\
};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This, indeed changes the tick labels of either axis. But now the follow up question: I would like to drop the 10 basis notation on the x-axis (y-axis is fine the way it is). I tried:

xtickten={e^{1},e^{2}} 

(And variations of this).

As it is its reverse, hoping that I would get an x-axis similar to the Matlab plot (bottom) shown in my openings post. Unfortunately, this does not work.

Comment: @Jos Please see my updated answer.

Comment: This works like a champ! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the existing answer didn't work correctly, because some values were still represented differently, e. g. `20` was rendered as `19.99`.

Now, I finally managed to solve the problem by inserting the line `log ticks with fixed point` into the `\begin{axis}[...]` options in the `.tikz` file:

```
\begin{axis}[%
...,
log ticks with fixed point
]
...
```

With `matlab2tikz`, this can be achieved using the following code:

```
matlab2tikz(tikzFileName, ...
   'extraaxisoptions', 'log ticks with fixed point'... % this line is new
);
```